# How to include struct variable declared in a header file in more than one source files?

Tags: c

I need a struct variable declared and defined in a header file to be accessible from more than one source files but I get a linker error. I'm putting small source code here. Linker error is

main.obj : error LNK2005: _a already defined in library.obj

fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

header.h

```
struct Student {
    char *FirstName;
    char *LastName;
};

struct Student a = {"John", "Jackson"};
```

library.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

void PrintStudentName(struct Student *name)
{
    printf("%s\n%s\n", name->FirstName, name->LastName);
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"


void PrintStudentName(struct Student *name);

int main()
{
    PrintStudentName(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace this definition line in the header

```
struct Student a = {"John", "Jackson"};
```

with this declaration:

```
extern struct Student a;
```

This declares a global variable of type `struct Student`.

Move the definition into one of the C files to complete the fix:

```
// This goes into one of the C files, does not matter which one.
struct Student a = {"John", "Jackson"};
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are right, I wrote "array" initially, and then went through and changed it to regular `struct`. Unfortunately, I missed one "array". Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Do not have definitions in a header file. These are solely meant to hold the declaration. The definition has to go into an implementation file (`*.c`). Think of the header file like the interface.

Disclaimer: I very well know ther might be exceptions to this rule. Also `typedef` is actually a definition, but one could just see it as an alias for the actual declaration (this is different from C++, btw).